# MVC 4 not redirecting to mobile for Android v4+?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am finding certain devices are not being redirected to the .Mobile.cshtml counterpart automatically. Is there a way to fix this or force mobile based on screen resolution via HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add a little piece of Javascript to create a cookie with Javascript's

```
 window.screen.availHeight
 window.screen.availWidth
```

and then on the server side inspect the cookie in the _PageStart.cshtml (which runs before each page is returned) and and if it meets your requirements override with

```
HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Mobile)
```